# Could not connect to ProximityService in Android studio

Tags: android-studio, service, sdk, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am doing a BLE beacon project in Android studio using SDK provided by 
https://developer.kontakt.io/android-sdk/quickstart/

It is showing below error when I run that program.

```
vCould not connect to ProximityService. Please check if the ProximityService is registered in AndroidManifest.xml
```

I have already registered the service in AndroidManifest.xml .

```
<service android:name="com.kontakt.sdk.android.ble.service.ProximityService" android:exported="false"/>
```

still showing the error.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest adding

```
<service android:name="com.kontakt.sdk.android.ble.service.ProximityService"/>
```

into your AndroidManifest.xml

worked for me